# Clicking feeling when I pedal

Tags: clicking

I've been riding my bike for quite some time now, and I've noticed I get a clicking feeling when I'm pedaling. I've tried checking the rear derailleur's shifting, tension screws and the derailleur hanger, and the bike still has the clicking feeling.

I don't hear the clicking sound but I feel it, can someone help me please.

Comment: Is it a single rhythmic click (even if not felt every revolution of crank or wheel), or is it a series of click/pop in fast succession.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A felt clicking is likely to be a bottom bracket or pedal bearing problem. Chain problems tend to be audible clicking or clattering.

If the click is felt on one side only that points to a pedal bearing problem rather than bottom bracket.

A constant stiffness, roughness or 'notchiness' as the cranks turn would indicate a worn out bottom bracket bearing.

You can check the pedals by simply turning them by hand. If they don't turn smoothly the bearings need greasing, servicing or replacing.

You can also check the bottom bracket in a similar way by turning the crank by hand. Taking the chain off the chainrings makes it easier to feel stiffness or roughness in the bearings. Also check for play (slight looseness) of the crank axle in the bottom bracket bearing.

If you are not familiar with bike repair, it’s best to have a local bike repair shop check it out. Bottom bracket replacement is best done by a repair shop in any case as special tools are needed.

Comment: The clicking i feel is not once per revolution, i keep feeling it simutaniously

Comment: @LamMunnJun Simultaneously with what? Do you mean it's a constant clicking?

Comment: yes, it clicks constantly. it started hapening  when i cleaned my bike. sorry for the bad english...

Comment: Same happened to me today. Omg.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause could be dry or worn pedal bearings. I had a click some time ago, on every one revaluation of of the pedals.
If you're capable to do this yourself strip down your pedals and fit new bearings and grease.
If nothing else it will eliminate the peddles.